# How do i create a nested dictionary iteratively?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from a given list, nesting elements as shown below.  For instance, given:

```
lst = range(1, 11)
```

how do I create a function to create a nested dictionary from this list:

```
dic = {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: {9: 10}}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: I posted an answer below, but just curious - why do you need this, what problem are you actually trying to solve? There might be a more elegant way to do it...

Comment: @plamut I have created a web crawler that extract every urls from a web domain and i want to create a nested dictionary to see which url lead to which url.

Comment: don't think a highly nested dictionary is your best option.  will be difficult to work with.

Comment: @ShpielMeister What do you think i should do ?

Comment: look at https://networkx.github.io. it has lots of tools for the sort of work you seem to be interested in.

Comment: I will, thanks a lot.

Comment: the nested dictionary would also break down if there is only one or zero urls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reverse your list (or better range object). Take the last (now first) element as start value and  create a new dict in each iteration through the rest of the reversed list:

```
>>> r = reversed(range(1, 11))
... d = next(r)
... for x in r:
...     d = {x: d}
... d
...
{1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: {9: 10}}}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `functools.reduce`.

```
import functools

lst = range(1, 11)
functools.reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(lst))
# {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: {9: 10}}}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can build it from inside out:

```
result = {9: 10}

for i in range(8, 0, -1):
    temp = {i: result}
    result = temp    

print(result)
# outputs {1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: {9: 10}}}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start from the innermost value, working outward.
At each step, use the previous step's dict as the new `val`.

```
def nest_dict(lst):
    my_dict = lst[-1]
    for val in lst[-2::-1]:
        my_dict = {val: my_dict}
    return my_dict

print nest_dict(range(1, 11))
```

Output:

```
{1: {2: {3: {4: {5: {6: {7: {8: {9: 10}}}}}}}}}
```